# sudo as user use current user folder. Why?

Tags: linux, sudo

Running the command `sudo -u www-data composer install` results in an error message, showing that the directory `/home/dev/.composer` is not writable.
`dev` is user which called the command.

Why does `composer` use the home directory of `dev` and not `www-data`?

Comment: Would you settle for ‘‘some answer‘‘, or do you want one specific to your situation?    :-)    ⁠

Comment: I want to understand why composer does not use /home/www-data/.composer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the `-H` option.

From the man page:

```
-H
    The -H (HOME) option requests that the security policy set the HOME environment variable to the home directory of the target user (root by default) as specified by the password database. Depending on the policy, this may be the default behavior.
```

In your comment you specified that you want to know *why* this happens. The answer is that `sudo` has many compile-time options. Since you did not specify which distribution you are running, I'm going to assume your distribution has set the option to preserve the `$HOME` environment variable.